# swig-template testing condition with subdocument

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express, swig-template

I have a json:

```
var json = [{
        a: "asdf",
        b: "a",
        c: {1:{z:30,x:20,y:50},2:{z:30,x:50,y:30}}
    },
    {
        a: "fdsa",
        b: "o",
        c: {1:{z:10,x:20,y:50},2:{z:0,x:20,y:30}}
    }
]
```

I want to have a condition to check:

- if any item `z`, `x`, or `y` in the `c` object is greater than `30`, show the value for `a`

Is this possible? I did some research but couldn't find any answers.
Please help! Thanks!
I tried

```
{% for c,b in json.c %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use case is incredibly complex and probably better done server-side, but here's a way you can do it in swig...

```
{% for item in json %}
  {% set show = false %}
  {% for set in item.c %}
    {% for k in set %}
      {% if k > 30 %}
        {% set show = true %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
  {% if show %}
    {{ item.a }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: sorry, i only want to show As. this would return all the Cs